# Insert barcode after order ID in a list of orders generated by Volusion

Tags: jquery, barcode, repeat, html, orders

I have an order receipt page auto generated by our system.  I need to add barcodes for each order number.  I have the basis set up, but I am running into two problems.

1) The barcode is printing using the first order number each time. I need each order to print its own bar code right below. (orders are in sequential order, but sometimes can skip order numbers)

2) The jquery is running multiple times as the system is going to place the code after each order. I cannot remove the jquery after each order, so how can I make it only run once after all orders have been loaded to the single document.

Below is a small piece of the entire order.  I have used table width and font size to declare the areas I need as the system did not give them ids or classes.  The only nice thing is font size 3 is never used anywhere else and same as table width 180, so I believe I will be fine in both cases.  Thank you for your help.

jQuery code

```
$("table[width='180']").after("<img id='bar_code'");

$('img#bar_code').attr('src', 'http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=' + $("font[size='3']").children().html() + '&style=197&type=C128B&width=150&height=50&xres=1&font=3');
```

HTML code

```
    <table width=180 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr> 
        <td width=90 align=left colspan="2"><b><font style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">PACKING SLIP</font></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td width=90 align=left><b>Date:</b></td>
        <td width=90><b>Order#:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td width=75 align=left> 05/17/2011 </td>
        <td><font size=3><b>10122</b></font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("table[width='180']").after("<img id='bar_code'");

$('img#bar_code').attr('src', 'http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=' + $("font[size='3']").children().html() + '&style=197&type=C128B&width=150&height=50&xres=1&font=3');
</script>

    <table width=180 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr> 
        <td width=90 align=left colspan="2"><b><font style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">PACKING SLIP</font></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td width=90 align=left><b>Date:</b></td>
        <td width=90><b>Order#:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td width=75 align=left> 05/17/2011 </td>
        <td><font size=3><b>10123</b></font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("table[width='180']").after("<img id='bar_code'");

$('img#bar_code').attr('src', 'http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=' + $("font[size='3']").children().html() + '&style=197&type=C128B&width=150&height=50&xres=1&font=3');
</script>


    <table width=180 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr> 
        <td width=90 align=left colspan="2"><b><font style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">PACKING SLIP</font></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td width=90 align=left><b>Date:</b></td>
        <td width=90><b>Order#:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td width=75 align=left> 05/17/2011 </td>
        <td><font size=3><b>10124</b></font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("table[width='180']").after("<img id='bar_code'");

$('img#bar_code').attr('src', 'http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=' + $("font[size='3']").children().html() + '&style=197&type=C128B&width=150&height=50&xres=1&font=3');
</script>


    <table width=180 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr> 
        <td width=90 align=left colspan="2"><b><font style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">PACKING SLIP</font></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td width=90 align=left><b>Date:</b></td>
        <td width=90><b>Order#:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td width=75 align=left> 05/17/2011 </td>
        <td><font size=3><b>10127</b></font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("table[width='180']").after("<img id='bar_code'");

$('img#bar_code').attr('src', 'http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=' + $("font[size='3']").children().html() + '&style=197&type=C128B&width=150&height=50&xres=1&font=3');
</script>
```

Comment: With all do respect what do you mean by this.  I am just hoping someone can help me out.  I am assuming I am missing something small and not vary familiar with jQuery.  Thank you again and I do hope you might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your headline was written IN ALL CAPS, someone else fixed this for you. Writing in all caps is considered as shouting (and rude)

Comment: I do apologize for being rude as it was unintentional.  You do learn something new ever day and this was my lesson for the day.  I do really need some help, so what can I do for you to give me some tips on this issue I need resolved above.

Comment: I took a look at your code, but the barcodes don't even appear onscreen.  I think that you would get a better response if you were to break this up into two questions (one for each problem in your list), and also provide a link to a http://jsfiddle.net so that it's easy for folks to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a bit late, but I was browsing through unanswered questions and noticed you forgot to close your image tags. In your script, by changing this:

```
$("table[width='180']").after("<img id='bar_code'");
```

to this:

```
$("table[width='180']").after("<img id='bar_code'>");
```

The script works perfectly...